# Prove that $n^2 > n+1 \quad\forall n \geq 2$ using mathematical induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, proof-verification, induction

> Prove $n^2 > n+1$ for $ n \geq 2$ using mathematical induction

So I attempted to prove this, but I'm not sure if this is a valid proof.

Base case, $n = 2$
$$
2^2 > 2+ 1 
$$
$n = k + 1$, induction on $n$
$$
(k+1)^2 > k + 2
$$
$k^2 + 2k + 1 > k + 2$ and by assumption, we know that $k^2 > k + 1$. so we can now write:
\begin{gather}
k^2 + 2k + 1 > 2k + 2\\
k^2 + 1 > 2\\
\end{gather}
$k^2 -1 > 0$ and since $n$ has to be $\geq 2$, the left hand side of the inequality will always be positive, making the statement a tautology.

Does this prove the original statement? If not, how do you do it?

Comment: See [Prove $n^2>(n+1)$ for all integers $ n \geq 2$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479937/prove-n2-n1-for-all-integers-n-geq-2)

Comment: The proof as presented is quite difficult to decipher. You should clearly state the inductive hypothesis, and what you are trying to prove in the inductive step.

Comment: "Does this prove the original statement?" No. What you wrote is not a proof, but a sequence of algebraic manipulations that seem to be relevant to the proof. What is missing is the most important part, namely all the explanations connecting them and making the argument coherent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$\begin{align}
k^2&\ge k+1\tag{1}\\
k^2+2k&\ge 3k+1\tag{2}\\
k^2+2k+1&\ge 3k+2\tag{3}\\
k^2+2k+1&\ge 3k+2\ge k+2\tag{4}\\
(k+1)^2&\ge (k+1)+1\tag{5}\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Would you mind explaining how you got the 4th line? I understand k^2+2k+1 ≥ 3k+2, but now sure how the second inequality gets there.

Comment: The 4th one, where there's a string of inequalities

Answer (score 2):

> Suppose it is true for $n=k(\ge 2)$ i.e. $k^2>k+1$

For $n=k+1$

$(k+1)^2=k^2+1+2k>(k+1)+1+2k=3k+2>k+2$

Answer (score 1):

facts:

- Since $n>2$, $n^2>4>3$
- Induction hyp: $n^2>n+1$

Proof: $(n+1)^2=n^2+2n+1>3+2n+1=2n+4=2(n+2)>n+2=(n+1)+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that $2^2 > 2+1$ and then that for $n \geq 1 , d/dx(x^2)=2x> d/dx(x)=1$

Answer (score 0):

consider

$\begin{align}(k+1)^2&=k^2+1+2k\\
&>k+1+1+2k\\
&=k+2+2k\\
&>k+2\quad (\because k\geq 2)
\end{align}$

Answer (score 0):

$k^2>k+1\\ \implies k(k-1)>1\\ \implies k((k+1)-2)>1\\\implies k(k+1)>2k+1>1\\\implies(k+1)((k+1)-1)>1\\ \implies (k+1)^2>(k+1)+1$

Answer (score 0):

$$n^2 > n+1 \equiv n > 1+(1/n); \quad \forall n \geq 2.$$ 
Now it is obviously true for $n=2$ and if it is true for $n$, it is true also for $n+1$ because the left side increases and the right side decreases when going to $n+1$ from $n$.